# Facebook app login request do not open in FB iOS app , it opens in Safari mobile browser

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I used FBSDK for get user information. But user request permission pop in a safari mobile browser. I need to open FB app in ios instead of popping safari browser, but browser should show up if user didn't download ios fb app. How can i achieve this one ?  ( I tested this on my iPhone 5s and still pop the safari instead of native FB app , but here i attached the simulator image )

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using the latest `FBSDK` and running on `iOS 9.0+` which supports `SFSafariViewController`.

`FBSDK` has added support for `SFSafariViewController` so instead of opening in `Safari`, it will open directly in your app in `SFSafariViewController.` This should be fine for your purposes.

On earlier versions of `iOS` it will still open in `Safari`.

Comment: So can we changed that, and open in FB app instead ?